# MySQL query for finding the most liked video this month

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a table of songs each with a unique id and publish date

```
id | name | pub_date
```

Also a table containing likes which have the video id, user id making the like and also the user who uploaded the videos id:

```
song_id | user_id | songuser_id
```

The query I need to make is to find the 10 most liked videos that have been uploaded in the current month. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT songs.id, songs.name, songs.pub_date, COUNT(likes.song_id) as likecount 
FROM `songs` INNER JOIN `likes` on songs.id = likes.song_id
WHERE MONTH(CAST(songs.pub_date as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) 
AND YEAR(CAST(songs.pub_date as date)) = YEAR(NOW()) 
ORDER BY likecount DESC LIMIT 5
```

But I only seem to return 1 result. I think the issue I'm having is to do with grouping the likes but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause since you aggregated on of the columns in your `SELECT` clause,

```
SELECT..
FROM...JOIN...
WHERE...
GROUP BY songs.id, songs.name, songs.pub_date
ORDER BY...
LIMIT...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DISTINCT/GROUP?

```
SELECT 
   songs.id, songs.name, songs.pub_date, COUNT(likes.song_id) as likecount
FROM
   songs
INNER JOIN likes ON likes.song_id = songs.id
WHERE
   MONTH(CAST(songs.pub_date as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) 
   AND 
   YEAR(CAST(songs.pub_date as date)) = YEAR(NOW()) 
GROUP BY
   songs.id  
ORDER BY
   likecount DESC 
LIMIT 5
```